Is integration semi-algebraic?
I am learning a bit of semi-algebraic geometry and I have looked into a bunch of examples of functions which are semi-algebraic. In particular I have tried to understand whether the function
$$ F: (0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, t \rightarrow \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} 1_{\{f\leq t\}}(x) dx $$
is a semi-algebraic function if $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a semi-algebraic function and $\{ f\leq t\}$ is a bounded set for all $t>0$. The Tarski-Seidenberg theorem tells us that if we could cast integration in a first-order logic formula, then we would be good to go. The problem which I encountered while trying that is that I do not manage to cast "taking partitions" into the desired form (essentially as $\mathbb{N}$ is not a semi-algebraic set).
Thus, my question is whether $F$ always needs to be semi-algebraic? If it fails for a general semi-algebraic $f$ would it work if $f$ is a polynomial (again with bounded sublevel sets)?
In the case where $f$ is a polynomial with rational coefficients it seems that $F$ is at least analytic by Theorem $9$ of (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.11705)
Lairez, Pierre, Marc Mezzarobba, and Mohab Safey El Din. "Computing the volume of compact semi-algebraic sets." Proceedings of the 2019 on International Symposium on Symbolic and Algebraic Computation. 2019.

Consider the function $$f(x,y) =\begin{cases} x & \text{if }1\leq x\leq 2 \text{ and }0\leq y\leq \frac{1}{x}\\
|x|+|y|+2& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
Then $f$ is semi-algebraic, $\{f\leq t\}$ is bounded for all $t>0$, and for $1\leq t\leq 2$, $\{f\leq t\}$ is the region in the plane bounded by $x=1$, $x=t$, $y=0$, and $y=\frac{1}{x}$. Then the function mapping $t$ to the area of this region agrees with $\ln(t)$ in the interval $[1,2]$, so this function is not semi-algebraic.

Thank you! Is this an artifact of the discontinuity of $f$ or would you expect that this is irrelevant?

The continuous function $f(x,y) = \max(|x|,|y|,|xy|)$ seems to have the same property of giving a log.
